# PHP/SQL - Return boolean result from SQL query between two dates

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, boolean

I've been asked to build a scheduler to display special offers on a website based on start/end dates. Part of that is to conditionally display a link to the page if there is a valid offer in place. But I'm completely at a loss.

The following query fetches any current offers which fall within the correct dates:

```
$now = date('Y-m-j');
$sql = "SELECT * FROM sample WHERE date_from <= '".$now."' AND date_to > '".$now."'";
```

I've not been able to develop this query to return a TRUE/FALSE value (which I need for the existing navigational structure - created by another developer). There've been some posts stating to use EXISTS() or SELECT CASE WHEN EXISTS() on the existing query, followed by THEN/ELSE for the output. But after hours of trying to crack this I've only managed to garner errors.

I know it's probably possible to work around this, but I want to return a boolean from the SQL query itself.

Comment: you want true if that query returns 1 or more rows?

Comment: Something like: SELECT COUNT(1) is_exists FROM sample WHERE date_from <= '".$now."' AND date_to > '".$now."

Comment: Yeah Dagon, if at least one row is returned then there'll be an offer, so "TRUE" to show the navigation.

Comment: For my example: if ($row->is_exists > 0) { ...

Comment: Amazing, see my answer below.  Near the end I mention the *_num_rows() php functions.  Depending on your database you can request the number of rows the query returns.  It is then not necessary to do extra logic just and simple if( pg_num_rows($res) > 0 ) {stuff;}

Comment: You will not find anything that returns a strictly boolean value for having 1 or more rows.  Since that's a trivial issue any programmer could write a loop to check.

Answer (score 2):

case should work:

```
select
CASE 
  WHEN date_from <= '".$now."' AND date_to > '".$now."' THEN 'TRUE'
  ELSE 'FALSE'
END

from yourtable
```

perhaps better

```
SELECT exists (
  SELECT * FROM sample WHERE date_from <= '".$now."' AND date_to > '".$now."') as BOO
```

BOO will be 1 if there is a match

Comment: How would I retrieve the results from that query?

Comment: This has worked, but I need to return a simple true or false overall if there's at least one true. This is the last part of my problem.

Comment: LIMIT 1 with give you one true\false

Answer (score 0):

PHP database queries return resources to the result of the query.
The result is an array or object of elements returned by the select statement.

If you want to return a boolean from the sql query itself.  Then you must change your * (asterisk) to something that is a boolean.

Depending on the database you are using, the exact syntax and functionality available changes.  But let's assume microsoft sql or postgres..

Postgres:

```
$sql = "SELECT (count(*)>0) as bool_result FROM sample WHERE date_from <= '".$now."' AND date_to > '".$now."'";
```

Microsoft SQL:

```
$sql = "SELECT (case when count(*)>0 then 1 else 0 end) as int_result FROM sample WHERE date_from <= '".$now."' AND date_to > '".$now."'";
```

Microsoft SQL uses the tiny int or bit for booleans.  So there is no way to return a strictly speaking "Boolean".  Hence the case when structure for the 1 or 0 from the boolean comparison.

If you want to know if ANY rows are returned and you care not the result set, then maybe mssql_num_rows or pg_num_rows is more your answer.  Both return the number of rows in the query result set.  You could then compare that to being equal to 0 or 1.

This is about as close to an answer you can get without supplying a code example and more details.

Here's an example:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM sample WHERE date_from <= '".$now."' AND date_to > '".$now."'";
$res = pg_query($sql);
if( pg_num_rows($res) > 0 ) 
    ShowNav();
```

Comment: I think OP should be checking if any results return from his query, something like `$rowcount=mysqli_num_rows($result);`, then `if($rowcount == 0){ //false...}else{//true..}`